# OpenCV getWindowImageRect returning size not matching resolution

Tags: python, windows, opencv, dpi

I'm trying to get the screen position of my window using opencv

```
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    print(cv2.getWindowImageRect('test'))
```

When I move my window to the bottom right corner to the screen it outputs
`(1484, 895, 500, 500)` so it looks like it thinks that my screen resolution is 1500x900 while in reality it's 2240x1400. Why does this happen and how can I make sure that the code returns correct values for every screen resolution?

Edit:
As wohlstad noticed this is happening because my windows "display settings -> scale and layout" is set to 150%

Comment: Which OS are you using ? If Windows - did you change the DPI (under "display settings -> scale and layout") to 150% ?

Comment: @wohlstad yes to all

Comment: So it seems like `getWindowImageRect` takes into accout the global scaling. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the original resultion into account. Just thought it might steer you towards the solution.